# UILocalNotification count in iOS if Repetitive Notification provided

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I am developing alarm application in my application the user can add alarm with repeat mode also, so i used
Eg:

```
  NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
  NSDateComponents *componentsForFireDate = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear |  NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute| NSCalendarUnitSecond | NSCalendarUnitWeekday) fromDate: [dictionaryForAlarm objectForKey:AlarmDate]];

    // every day
    localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay;
    localNotification.fireDate=[calendar dateFromComponents:componentsForFireDate];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

As i have seen the iOS allows to schedule only 64 local notification for each application.

> So i want to know that weather in my repeat alarm if i am scheduling
>   one notification with repeat interval then how many notification will
>   iOS consider for this? (Weather Single or Depends on repeat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just one, if you use `repeatInterval` the system consider only one notification. You easily check by asking the `UIApplication` instance the `scheduledLocalNotifications`.

Comment: thank you buddy, each object of notification is considered as single one by iOS